# Charger turns off when laptop have battery in it

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, battery, charging, charger

My E6430 laptop works fine with only charger or only battery. But **when I plug charger after inserting the battery the charger turns OFF**. But my laptop stay ON on battery. So, I cannot charge my battery.

I have tried the following things:

1. Used different charger.
2. Power button method for static discharge.
3. Resetting the BIOS.

Comment: How much charge does the battery hold? Some manufacturers install power management software on the computer that stop a charger from charging the battery when its over 80% filled, to spare the battery.

Answer (score 0):

> laptop works fine with only charger or only battery  ...  Used
> different charger.

You need to get the laptop serviced. There is most likely a fault in the charging circuit (inside the laptop) that is causing this issue.

> I cannot charge my battery.

Some laptops have charging threshold management software, but this does not appear to be your issue because even with threshold management (I have that here) charging and having a battery installed do not usually conflict as is happening here.

Comment: Or... there is a power management software installed that disables charging when the battery is above 80%, or whatever is configured in the software.